# Filter and replace all the occurence of string in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace, nsstring

I have a data in following format

```
   field1 = "sometext";
    field2 = text2;
    field3 =         (
                    {
            uniqueId = 123;
        },
                    {
            uniqueId = 234;
        }
    );
    field4 = "anothertext";
```

I need to convert it like this

```
"field1":"sometext",
"field2":"text2",
"field3": [
                {
        "uniqueId":"123",
    },
                {
        "uniqueId":"234",
    }
],
"field4":"anothertext"
```

ie replace '=' with : and append to and end of string before and after '=' with " and ; with ',' How should I proceed?

Comment: Are you just trying to convert an object to JSON?

Comment: What is the object type you used for above format it's a string object or dictionary object or else do you have any file

Comment: Use `NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];`, where `dictionary` is that object you displayed in your first example. See [NSJSONSerialization Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: The object is a string object, actually I have a textview in which I will copy this log and I'm trying to convert it into a JSON kind of format.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have a dictionary with a couple string key/value pairs and an array of other dictionaries that you are trying to convert to JSON.

If I am incorrect on this and completely missed what you are trying to accomplish I apologize. Based on your desired end result this might be a simpler approach.

Your current initial string could be stored like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         @"sometext",   @"field1",
                                         text2,         @"field2",
                                         myDictArray,   @"field3",
                                         @"anothertxt", @"field4"
                      , nil];
```

and then converted into the format you desire using json conversion.

I have a method that I use for that.

```
+(NSData*)jsonDatafromDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary*) dictionary
{
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                                                   options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSString *errorDesc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error creating json data from dictionary: %@", error.localizedDescription];
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", errorDesc);
        jsonData = nil;
        return nil;
    }
    else
        return jsonData;
}
```

To view the data as an NSString you can use this:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

To convert json back into a dictionary format I use this method:

```
+(NSMutableDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONString:(NSString*)jsonString
{
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"FAILED TO CREATE DICTIONARY FROM JSON STRING: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    jsonData = nil;
    error = nil;
    return jsonDict;
}
```

----- EDIT -----
Based on your comment below this might get you started. The only thing I haven't added is the code to add in the quotes where needed … I need to think on that for a few minutes, this should replace all the other characters like you wanted though.

Note: I have not tested this but should get you started.

```
-(NSString*)convertString:(NSString*)ps
{
    NSString *cs = @"";
    cs = [ps stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@","];
    cs = [cs stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"["];
    cs = [cs stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@"]"];
    cs = [cs stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@":"];
    return cs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I have a textview in which I will copy this log and I'm trying to convert it into a JSON kind of format. Currently I'm storing the textview value in a NSString, is it possible to covert from that using NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: Updated my answer, check the edit at the bottom. I need to think about the quotes and my brain is fried atm. If you don't come up with a solution I'll check back and try to finish it when I'm thinking a little clearer.